# Equation with two variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

im studying for an exam and i came up across this problem

find all integers $m,n$ that satisfy the equation

$\ (m+2n+1)(m-n+2)=5 $

i tried to open up the parenthesis and then finding out one of the variables and then substituing it into the first equation, would that be correct?
thank you all!

ps. sorry if it's an easy question!
pps the answers would be  $m=2 ,n= -1$ or $m= -4 , n = -1 $

Comment: Do you know what the divisors of $5$ are?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you aware of the fact that, if $m$ and $n$ are integers, then $m+2n+1$ and $m-n+2$ are integers too?

Comment: Thank you! i was thinking about it incorrectly. i appreciate you taking time out to answer the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(m + 2 n + 1) (m - n + 2)=5$$
As $m,n$ are integers we can have
$$
\begin{cases}
m + 2 n + 1=1\\
 m - n + 2=5\\
\end{cases}
$$
Or
$$
\begin{cases}
m + 2 n + 1=5\\
 m - n + 2=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
or
$$
\begin{cases}
m + 2 n + 1=-1\\
 m - n + 2=-5\\
\end{cases}
$$
Or
$$
\begin{cases}
m + 2 n + 1=-5\\
 m - n + 2=-1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful, and makes sense!